# list of nested dictionaries to pandas dataframe (type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_items')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am a beginner in python. I have a nested dictionary. I tried to get the pandas data frame from the list of nested dictionaries.

[Sample file of dict in pickle](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s1kczdm6mgfpbso/AAAPXHVRDOI3Dbxd6dyelSI6a?dl=0)

The nested dict called `user_dict` is as follow:

```
[{'1000003': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 0.0}},  {'1000007': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 856.0786277323101,    'walk': 2546.869189662443,    'bike': 0.0}},  
{'1000008': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 34189.569164682835,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 0.0}},  
{'1000009': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 9847.472668350396}}]
```

I want to get the data frame like this:

[Expected dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edjLG.png)

I used the code based on Igor Raush's answer ([Getting pandas dataframe from list of nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946927/getting-pandas-dataframe-from-list-of-nested-dictionaries/41947195#41947195?newreg=3c66df7ca1e44d5da5e20ccd48dadea1))

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in user_dict))).T
```

But it did not work for me, instead, it threw an error as such:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8ea27c4b8e43> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in user_dict))).T

AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_items'
```

It works with the classmethod `pd.concat`, but I have more than 200k observations, so I am looking for efficient solution. Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
dics = [{'1000003': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 0.0}},  {'1000007': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 856.0786277323101,    'walk': 2546.869189662443,    'bike': 0.0}},  
       {'1000008': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 34189.569164682835,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 0.0}},  
       {'1000009': {'car': 0.0,    'car_passenger': 0.0,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 9847.472668350396}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['car','car_passenger','pt','walk','bike' ])
index_list = []
for dic in dics: 
    key = list(dic.keys())[0]
    index_list.append(key)
    df = df.append(dic[key], ignore_index=True)
df.index = index_list
df

#Output: 

        car     car_passenger   pt          walk        bike
1000003 0.0     0.000000        0.000000    0.00000     0.000000
1000007 0.0     0.000000        856.078628  2546.86919  0.000000
1000008 0.0     34189.569165    0.000000    0.00000     0.000000
1000009 0.0     0.000000        0.000000    0.00000     9847.472668
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. It works perfectly. Supposed I have another level of nest added to the dict [Sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwpwubbg1g1msgb/agents_dist_attr_default.pickle?dl=0). What should I adjust in order to get data frame like this: [expected dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pix63rrre80bsyk/Bildschirmfoto%202021-03-04%20um%2010.57.40%20AM.png?dl=0). Could you give me some leads?

Comment: sorry, wrong sample data, I will upload it the new one here [correct sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rchgrvwbwawl5ye/agents_dist_attr_default.pickle?dl=0)

Comment: Can't see your data. I think the only differences is column number you need to arrange your df columns ```df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [ Actual Columns ])``` and please accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So data would look like this: `dics = [{'1000003': {'dist': {'car': 0.0,    'car_p': 0.0,    'pt': 0.0,    'walk': 0.0,    'bike': 0.0}, 'attribute': {'student': 'yes'}}}, 
        {'1000007': {'dist': {'car': 0.0,    'car_p': 0.0,    'pt': 856.0,    'walk': 2546.0,    'bike': 0.0}, 'attribute': {'student': 'no'}}}]`. Additional nest separating dist and attribute. By the way, thank you for your answer

Comment: Hope this helps: 
```index_list = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['car', 'car_p', 'pt', 'walk', 'bike', 'student'])
for dic in dics: 
    key = list(dic.keys())[0]
    index_list.append(key)
    df = df.append(dic[key]['dist'], ignore_index=True)
df.index = index_list
print(df)```

Comment: Again, thank you for time and help. But with the code, I got the NaN in the student column.

Comment: I don't get NAN values from your sample data

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to avoid typo, but still I get NaN value in student column. No worries, I will play with the code. Thank you

Comment: Did you use same sample data that you gave me on comments? Because maybe your real data has NAN values

Comment: Yes, I used the sample data from the comments. The real data in attribute section contains only `string`. Sorry for another question, when i use this code to process the data (>50000 observations), it took me about 10 minutes. What do you think about it?

Comment: Sounds reasonable because the code needs to traverse all nodes in the data.